# MVC 5 HTML Form Submit Not Firing

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been following along with a book titled Pro ASP.net and have come across a rather odd issue. I've got a Razor view linked to a controller, and on that view I'm using `@Html.BeginForm()`. However, the form doesn't submit when it contains anything other than a submit button. If I just have the button within `@Html.BeginForm` the view will kick over to my controller just fine. But when I put the rest of the form's contents inside, nothing happens when I hit the submit button.

**Relevant HTML from the view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditContact", "EditContact"))
{
    <div class="container">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyName != "Id")
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>@(property.DisplayName ?? property.PropertyName)</label>
                    @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName, Model.GetPropertyValue(property.PropertyName), new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessage(property.PropertyName)
                </div>
            }
        }
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Cancel", null, new {@class="btn btn-default"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Connected Controller**

```
namespace ActiveCampaign.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class EditContactController : Controller
    {
        private IContactRepository _repository;
        private ActiveApi _activeService = new ActiveApi();

        public EditContactController(IContactRepository contactRepository)
        {
            _repository = contactRepository;
        }

        public ActionResult Index(Contact contact)
        {
            return View("EditContact", contact);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditContact(Contact contact)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = _activeService.EditContact(contact);
                if (result)
                {
                    _repository.SaveContact(contact);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }

            return View("EditContact", contact);
        }

        public ActionResult Cancel()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `@Html.HiddenFor(...)` was the culprit! Why I'm not sure (especially since another application I wrote that uses it works just fine), but removing that makes everything work as it should.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the type of your button. The default type is `button`, which does nothing on its own. What you want is `submit`:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

Comment: Just tried that, but wound up getting the same result. If I remove everything but the button and its row from the container, it functions properly and the corresponding function is called. If I add everything back in then nothing.

Comment: You getting any errors in the console? Examine the rendered code as well. Browser tools are great for these annoyances.

Comment: I checked, and there's nothing showing up in the console... Tried deleting/remaking both the controller and the view, but that didn't do anything either, unfortunately.

Comment: Any forms in your _layout or above the code shown? If it works with everything else removed, try adding things back 1 at a time. Is it hitting the cancel action?

Comment: I think I may have found the culprit. Removing the `@Html.HiddenFor(...)` line allows it to run properly... which is a problem, as with what I'm doing I need access to that property after it gets returned, but don't want the user to be able to edit/touch it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to Add post method in your BeginForm. I think Edit your code like this below may work fine. And check for any tag misplacements also.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditContact", "EditContact",FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Just got in to work, so I figured I'd give this  a shot. I changed BeginForm to add in the Post method, and put the `@Html.HiddenFor(...)` line back in.

Just like before, nothing happens when I click on the Submit button when the `@Html.HiddenFor(...) line is included, even with the Post method added in. Thanks for the suggestion, though!